# can't access $state or $state.current

Tags: angularjs, routes, frontend, state, directive

I want set page titles which change according to route. I mean Responsive titles.

I have a directive in my module:

```
mainModule.directive("pageTitle", function($state){
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: "{{title}}",
    scope: {title: '=title'},
    link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
        scope.title=$state.current.data.title; //wrap this in $watch
        console.log('page state',$state.current.data.title);
    }
  } 
})
```

in my main.cshtml I have this title directive in head tags:

```
<title><page-title title="{{$state.current.data.title}}"></page-title></title>
```

And I have stateProvider in my config file:

```
$stateProvider
        .state('a-management', {
            name: 'aManState',
            url: '/a-management',
            template: '<div license-a permissions = permissions></div>',
            data: {title: 'A Management'}
        })
        .state('b-management/bs', {
            url: '/b-management/bs',
            template: '<b-management current-user = currentUser permissions = permissions></b-management>',
            data: {title: 'B Management'}
        })
```

And I used `ui-sref-active="active"` too.
Everything looks fine, but when I run website this doesn't work. I open the console and look what I have, looks like it can reach **$state** (by state service) but the its **current** property is empty.

Why can't my code reach current, so current.data too? Is there anything I missed?

Comment: may be duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17215656/how-to-detect-current-state-within-directive

Comment: @Jignesh Joisar I already did active thing

Comment: Create a isolated scope, do something like `scope.state = $state`, and put `{{state.current.name}}` in the template

Comment: Hi @codergirrl, I added a comment here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52538794/91017 on how to do this with a $stateChangeSuccess listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for helping guys, In this question cwbutler's answer solved this.

[[Set Page title using UI-Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23813599/set-page-title-using-ui-router][1])

Answer (score 0):

I am just going throw another solution where you wouldn't need to use a directive (may or may not be interested, but this is what I do). I essentially have a run command, that listens for state changes, and then update the page title through the root scope based on a title variable passed into the state. From there, the page title (index.html) is bound to the title in the root scope.

**app.js**

```
// Insert code here 
app.run(function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState) {
        $rootScope.title = toState.title || 'Default Title';
});


// Insert code here
.state('', {
    url: '/',
    title: 'Random Title'
}
```

**index.html**

```
    <head>
    <title ng-bind="title">Default Title</title>
    </head>
```

Hopefully this makes sense and helps you out?

Comment: thank you but it's still not working, no error given, still can't get titles so weird T_T

Comment: What part isn't getting the title? I guess I should also ask which version of ui-router are you using?

Comment: There is no title in any page. "angular-ui-router": "^1.0.20"

Comment: So, just for debugging, you may want to log and make sure that the stateChange is being caught when you change pages. You also will need to make sure that you bind the title properly. So, assuming you have some type of parent controller over the entire app, you will need to set the title variable in there

Comment: stateChange is not being caught because I put console.log and there's no output

Comment: Sorry I overlooked that you are using the newest version of ui-router. You would have to use transition hooks as described by @Fabio in his answer instead of listening for state changes. I can update my answer if you want?

Comment: Okay I will go on from that way. Thank you so much for attention

Answer (score 0):

With newest version of [UI-Router](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/) you can use **Transition Hooks** ([docs here](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/transitionhooks)) to achieve that result:

You can write your `page-title.directive.js` as:

```
mainModule.directive("pageTitle", function(){
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: "{{title}}",
    scope: {},
    controller: function ($scope, $transitions) {
        $transitions.onSuccess({}, function (transition) {
            //
            $scope.title = transition.to().title; // Your current state's title
        });
    }
  } 
})
```

And your state definition will be:

```
$stateProvider.state('myState', {
    url: '/',
    title: 'My State Title',
    ...
})
```

---

Always try to avoid accessing (or emitting on) **$rootScope** if it isn't your last chance to achieve your result.

Hope it helps.

Comment: this code is super good but it doesn't work too. no error again no title...

Comment: Make sure you are declaring your directive. No error let me thinks firstly on this kind of oversight.

Comment: you are so right directive doesnt work. I did like is that it true : <title pageTitle>{{title}}</title>

Comment: You should use it as: <div page-title></div>. Remember to convert to a "dashed" name your directive name when used inside a template.

Comment: still doesn't work. I guess in this part transition.to().title couldnt find title. but I don't know why.

Comment: This should help you with your problem, but for what are you saying i think that maybe there is no active state to display. Make sure you are activating a state with a title prop in his definition

Comment: I want to ask a question about active. I used active like this ui-sref-active="active" Is this true? Should I specify about title this line or I don't please help me

Comment: Yes, the usage will be similar, but you have to handle this "template injection" manually. ui-sref-active only cares about adding css classes but the behaviour is the same of your particular case